# NgClass condition checked only after certain events

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a project in Ionic, Angular and Typescript which uses the ngClass directive.

```
< div [ngClass]="{'fixed': isSectionVisible(0)}> ...
< /div>
```

The problem is that the value (the result of isSectionVisible) is checked only after certain events (clicks, form completion,etc), whereas I need it to be checked also after scrolling up and down the page.

I tried adding

```
on-mousemove="functionX()"
```

to the content of the page, so that the browser sees every mouse move as an event and so it checks the value of the function. It works on the PC, but doesn't work on mobile, as there's no mouse.

Any idea how can I make it check the result after scrolling? Thanks!

Comment: Default `ChangeDetectionStrategy`?

Comment: `ngClass` will evaluate that expression each `$digest` cycle - make sure your events are triggering one (non-Angular events don't)

Comment: Try adding `(mousemove)="functionX()"` instead.

Comment: Same. It only works on the PC.